# QWebView: Only disable javascript coming from websites?

Tags: javascript, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I'm currently writing a small browser, and would like to interact with pages via Javascript (for example for [GreaseMonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey)-like userscripts).

However I'd like to disable loading of javascript *of webpages* via `QWebSettings`. Now when I do something like:

```
settings = QWebSettings.globalSettings()
settings.setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, False)
```

javascript from the web doesn't work, but things like `evaluateJavaScript` or `addToJavaScriptWindowObject` of `QWebFrame` don't work anymore *either*.

I believe [dwb](http://portix.bitbucket.org/dwb/) which is based on WebKitGTK circumvents this by using the JavaScriptCore library directly.

Can I do something similiar, like maybe use [QtScript](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtscript.html) to evaluate the userscripts myself and bridge them to the webview somehow? Though this doesn't seem exactly like an easy solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I just noticed using `evaluateJavaScript()` on a `QWebElement` works even with javascript disabled.

This means at least I can do something like:

```
webview.page().mainFrame().documentElement().evaluateJavaScript("...")
```

and that works fine.